# UTC to Localized time given country initials

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, timezone

What would be the best way of converting a column of UTC time to the localized time, assuming I have a column of country initials?

eg

```
   UTC          Country  
----------   |  --------  
1480597215        FR
1480544735        RU
```

to

```
   UTC          Country     Localized time (example)
----------   |  --------    ---------------
1480597215        FR       datetime.datetime(2016, 12, 2, 0, 0, 15, tzinfo  = FR)
1480544735        RU
```

I understand there are timezone issues (eg, Different parts of US is on different timezones) but assuming an approximate mapping (eg, all of US follows central time)

What would be the best approach for this? the pytz library needs actual timezones (eg, 'Asia/Malaysia') but I only have the country codes.

Thank you! :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use vectorized [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html) + [`tz_localize`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.tz_localize.html) for `UTC` datetime and then `apply` for converting to timezones:

```
from pytz import country_timezones

df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['UTC'], unit='s').dt.tz_localize('UTC')
df['tz']=df.apply(lambda x: x['date'].tz_convert(country_timezones(x['Country'])[0]), axis=1)
print (df)
          UTC Country                      date                         tz
0  1480597215      FR 2016-12-01 13:00:15+00:00  2016-12-01 14:00:15+01:00
1  1480544735      RU 2016-11-30 22:25:35+00:00  2016-12-01 00:25:35+02:00
```

Create mask with [`notnull`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.notnull.html) and then apply solution only for values where `True`s:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'UTC': [1480597215, 1480597215, 1480597215, 1480544735], 
                   'Country': ['', np.nan, 'FR', 'RU']})
print (df)
  Country         UTC
0          1480597215
1     NaN  1480597215
2      FR  1480597215
3      RU  1480544735

df['UTC'] = pd.to_datetime(df['UTC'], unit='s', errors='coerce').dt.tz_localize('UTC')
mask = df['Country'].notnull() & (df['Country'] != '')
print (mask)
0    False
1    False
2     True
3     True
Name: Country, dtype: bool

df['tz'] = df[mask].apply(lambda x: x['UTC'].tz_convert(country_timezones(x['Country'])[0]), 
                          axis=1)
print (df)
  Country                       UTC                         tz
0         2016-12-01 13:00:15+00:00                        NaN
1     NaN 2016-12-01 13:00:15+00:00                        NaN
2      FR 2016-12-01 13:00:15+00:00  2016-12-01 14:00:15+01:00
3      RU 2016-11-30 22:25:35+00:00  2016-12-01 00:25:35+02:00
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use country_timezones of pytz :

```
import pytz
from datetime import datetime

timestamp = 1480597215
d = datetime.fromtimestamp(timestamp, pytz.timezone(pytz.country_timezones('fr')[0]))
print d
```

keep in mind that pytz.country_timezones returns a list of available timezone with respect to input.